# Using find to pass files to a jar

Tags: java, linux, bash, find

Using 'find' I'm planning to pass all files with a specific ending as an argument to a jar-file.

```
find $directory -type f -name "*.in"
```

Somehow this is supposed to happen:

java -jar MyJar-jar input.in

How can this be performed?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2):

```
find "$directory" -type f -name '*.in' -exec java -jar MyJar.jar {} \;
```

Replace `\;` with `+` if the application can take more than one file at a time as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

```
xargs -0 -a<(find $directory -type f -name '*.in' -print0) java -jar MyJar.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

```
java -jar MyJar.jar `find $directory -type f -name "*.in"`
```

should do the trick.